# How do I access an html element attribute with CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, cefsharp

Here is the example HTML segment of the page:

```
<dd class="row market-list_item">..</dd>
<dd class="row market-list_item">..</dd>
   <div class="cell" role="button" data-ember-action data ember-action-3019="3019">..</div>
   <div id="ember3020" class="ember-view cell price-buttons">
      <a role="button" class="price_tick price-button price-button--sell sell" data-ember-action data-ember-action-3021="3021">86.50</a>
      <a role="button" class="price_tick price-button price-button--buy buy" data-ember-action data-ember-action-3021="3022">96.75</a>
   </div>
</dd>
```

I have tried the following to retrieve the element attribute ember3020 from the div tag within the dd element.

```
var webval = chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName(' row market-list_item')[0].children[1].attibutes['id'].value; })();");
var response = webval.Result;
if (response.Success == false || response.Result.ToString() == null)
{
  // Do work here
}
```

webval.Results = null. I can't get the attribute value :( I am trying to get the id value ember3020. The data is dynamic and changes every few minutes. So, I don't know the id in advance.

UPDATE:

I solved this. This is what I found.

1. .attibutes['id'].value was wrong. This should have been .getAttributes('id')
2. Since this is an async call to get values I needed a process to wait. Here is what I found that worked.

https://gist.github.com/amaitland/7a41cc87b88dfcd30e0e

This allowed me to get the values when they were ready.

Comment: Can't you use `GetElementById()` directly?

Comment: The id changes every few minutes. So, I don't know what it is. This is why I am trying to get the id first.

Comment: The data is time sensitive and changes. I have to time it, get the ids of the elements I need, then select one of the elements by its id. Once I have the id a can use getelementbyid.

Comment: If this: `<div id="ember3020" class="ember-view cell price-buttons">` is the element you're trying to reach (to reach its `InnerHtml` elements, I suppose) and it's its `Id` that changes, does also it's `className` change? Or do you want to scrap the content of more than one `<dd class="row market-list_item">..</dd>` elements?

Comment: No. The class name is the same for the sub-element. Here is the structure, each dd element contains two sub-elements. I don't need the first sub-element. I need the id of the second element. The attribute "id" not the innerText. I can get the innerText of an element. I just have not found out how to get the attributes of an element, specifically the id attribute using CefSharp.

Comment: getElementsByClassName('row market-list_item')[0].children[1].attibutes['id'].value works using browser development tools. The CefSharp browser returns null.

Comment: Yes to your question. I need the ID from each dd sub-element.

Comment: I got it to work, sort of. While playing with different options to try to get this data I was successful, but only briefly! The data appeared intermittently. The call I am using is: var ClickMarket3 = @"document.getElementsByTagName('dd')['"+j+"].children[1].getAttribute('id');";
                JavascriptResponse result98 = await chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(ClickMarket3);
                if (result98.Result != null)
              {}  Where "j" is in a for loop to index the elements. I think the issue is the data is not getting back in time.

Comment: When are you calling EvaluateScriptAsync? If it works in DevTools then what you are seeing might be a matter of timing. If the content is dynamically generated then you might be executing too early.

Comment: There were a couple of issues I found and added them to the problem description. The timing was part of the problem. I found code that fixed this. It is linked in the description. Thank you for assisting with this!!!

Comment: For anyone else https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript has details on when you can execute JavaScript.